# How can I set response type in runtime (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm developing a Spring MVC application where I need to validate a form. My problem is next: I want to change the processing of returning data from my method in depending on some logic.

For example, I have a registration user page! If the user fields are valid I need to send a message to ajax on the registration page. But if they aren't valid I need to return the view name (or do redirect). How can I do it? Here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "save_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "common/add_user"; // Here I need to return the view name or do redirect
        } else {
            userManager.add(user);
            return "success... bla bla bla"; // Here I need to return some message.
        }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to redirect, your controlller method should look like public @ReponseBody String saveUser(rest remains same). If you want to redirect, remove responseBody. Your question is not precise to help. Also, you are already returning the view-name in common/add. So, choose one, either view or send it to Ajax.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes. You're right. But I'd like to know can I choose one (either view or send) in runtime? Can I choose it in depending on some logic? Maybe Spring has a mechanism for it...

Comment: As far as I know, no such mechanism, and no such requirement I have ever heard. Maybe some other user can help you out, but I doubt it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "save_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "common/add_user"; // Here I need to return the view name or do redirect
        } else {
            userManager.add(user);
            return "success... bla bla bla"; // Here I need to return some message.
        }
}
```

in your ajax, you can get the response data

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save_user",
    data: $("#user").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
    //get response data and process it 
     ...
    }
});
```

Hope this help!

Comment: This should work, as you can redirect the user based upon String received.